# Complete this mysterious grid

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

***On the basis of the characters that have filled the non coloured cells, which characters should fill the coloured cells to complete this mysterious grid?***

[image]

---

Hint 1:

> *Grouped into three categories, this grid is about five different colourful tales.*

---

Hint 2:

> *(35, 56) premiered in (Jan, 08). It was created by (V, None).*

Comment: Are colours important?

Comment: @ACB No. They're used just for differentiating purpose.

Comment: I think I see how the cells(squares) are connected, but I can't make sense of the whole grid

Comment: @Prim3numbah It may be helpful if you separate 6 columns into 3 groups of 2 columns each. First two columns are related to next two columns and final two columns. There is a mapping between those 3 groups.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's deduce the formatting on each set first:

> These are triplets of paired character sets. With each pair being diagonally connected to each other. This is given to us by the hint (35,36 - Jan,08 - V,None)

Now for what the characters represent:

> The first pair is the atomic number of the first characters in the title (35,56). The second pair is the premiere date of the show (Jan, 08). And the last pair represents the show's creator (V,None).

Using the hint:

> (35,36) is the elements for (Br, Ba) which are the first characters in Breaking Bad (and are also highlighted in the show's title card). (V, None) represents Vince Gilligan (the show's creator). V = Vanadium, and there's no element that is just G (or Gi), so that's why it's None. And it premiered in January 2008.

To Build out all of the sets and what they represent:

> 1. (red?,red?)-(Jan,99)-(None,C) = (?,?)-(Jan,99)-(?,C) = The Sopranos, Jan '99, by David Chase
>  2. (90,74)-(Jun,02)-(None,Si) = (Th,W)-(Jun,02)-(?,Si) = The Wire, Jun '02 by David Simon
>  3. (59,35)-(yellow?,yellow?)-(Pa,Sc) = (Pr,Br)-(?,?)-(Pa,Sc) = Prison Break, Aug '05 by Paul Scheuring
>  4. (35,56)-(Jan,08)-(V,None) = (Br,Ba)-(Jan,08)-(V,?) = Breaking Bad, Jan '08 by Vince Gilligan
>  5. (15,5)-(Sep,13)-(blue?blue?) = (P,B)-(Sep,13)-(?,?) = Peaky Blinders, Sep '13, by Steven Knight

Which leaves red as:

> (90,16)

And yellow as:

> (Aug,05)

And blue as:

> (S,K)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the solution, but I thought this could help others to find it.

> Months are replaced by their number. Octal ("ninal" actually) numbers (or dates) are replaced by their decimal equivalent. Chemical elements are replaced by their number. "None" is replaced by 0. So the grid becomes:

> [image: Grid with numbers (if I'm on the right track)]

Comment: @chandanr777 Please don't let me mislead others if I'm not on the right track.

Comment: Good way of thinking. However, everything should be left as it is. And the 'dates' may not be the dates.

Comment: But it might help if you convert the first two columns :)

Comment: Well, I converted the first 2 columns into chemical elements and traced arrows on the periodic table, it got me nowhere. Very interesting puzzle.

Comment: I think you are complicating yourself. This is just a knowledge puzzle and it is about what you make of this grid, it's alignment and the character in each cell.